# How can I set the title of ListPreference with the string defined in android:entries array?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I hope to change the title of ListPreference when I select a item.

For example, I hope that the title of ListPreference can display the string "Super" defined in `@string/RecordQuality_Super` when I select the first item.

At present, I can dislay the value "15" in my code, how can I display "Super" ?

```
final ListPreference my=(ListPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("RecordQuality");
my.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,Object newValue) {

       my.setTitle(newValue.toString());

        return true;
    }
});
```

the layout file

```
<ListPreference
        android:key="RecordQuality"
        android:defaultValue="8"
        android:entries="@array/RecordQualityOption"
        android:entryValues="@array/RecordQualityOption_values"
        android:title="@string/RecordQualityTitle"
        android:summary="@string/RecordQualitySummary"
        android:layout="@layout/layout_customize_preference_item"
     />
```

the string array

```
 <string-array name="RecordQualityOption">
        <item>@string/RecordQuality_Super</item>
        <item>@string/RecordQuality_High</item>
        <item>@string/RecordQuality_Medium</item>
        <item>@string/RecordQuality_Low</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="RecordQualityOption_values">
        <item>15</item>
        <item>8</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>
```

the translations

```
 <string name="RecordQuality_Super">Super</string>
    <string name="RecordQuality_High">High</string>
    <string name="RecordQuality_Medium">Medium</string>
    <string name="RecordQuality_Low">Low</string>
```

Comment: try this `my.setTitle(my.getValue());`

Comment: Sorry, it's not correct